# HPLIP Driver install fails on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, python3, hplip, lsb-release

I recently upgraded a 18.04 release to 20.04 (early, I know), and wiped away my manually installed 'hplip' package (3.16.11) and installed the official package from the release (3.20.3+dgfsg0-2).  All *seemed* to be well until I started getting messages to update my driver.  Making sure I had nothing else to print today, I followed the instructions only to have the 'hp-plugin' command fail to download the plugin with the following backtrace...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/hplip/ui5/plugindialog.py", line 248, in NextButton_clicked
    status, download_plugin_file, error_str = self.pluginObj.download(self.plugin_path,self.plugin_download_callback)
  File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/pluginhandler.py", line 254, in download
    core = core_install.CoreInstall()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/core_install.py", line 239, in __init__
    self.passwordObj = password.Password(ui_mode)
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/password.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.__readAuthType()  # self.__authType
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/password.py", line 110, in __readAuthType
    distro_name = get_distro_name().lower()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/password.py", line 78, in get_distro_name
    return distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name=False)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 122, in linux_distribution
    return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 677, in linux_distribution
    self.version(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 737, in version
    self.lsb_release_attr('release'),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 899, in lsb_release_attr
    return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 552, in __get__
    ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 1012, in _lsb_release_info
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Downloading the plugin program manually and trying to install it that way yielded the same result.  What's going on here?  It doesn't appear that the lsb_release module is missing, and running `/usr/bin/lsb_release -a` works fine and doesn't return any errors.

```
$ apt-cache policy hplip-gui
hplip-gui:
  Installed: 3.20.3+dfsg0-2
  Candidate: 3.20.3+dfsg0-2
  Version table:
 *** 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
$ dpkg -l | grep -i hplip
ii  hplip                                                       3.20.3+dfsg0-2                                     amd64        HP Linux Printing and Imaging System (HPLIP)
ii  hplip-data                                                  3.20.3+dfsg0-2                                     all          HP Linux Printing and Imaging - data files
ii  hplip-doc                                                   3.20.3+dfsg0-2                                     all          HP Linux Printing and Imaging - documentation
ii  hplip-gui                                                   3.20.3+dfsg0-2                                     all          HP Linux Printing and Imaging - GUI utilities (Qt-based)
```

Running the hp-plugin command from the command line prints the stack twice, and the first iteration has a few more complaints...

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 144, in apport_excepthook
    with os.fdopen(os.open(pr_filename,
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/crash/_usr_share_hplip_plugin.py.1000.crash'
```

I have no problem writing files as a regular user in /var/crash, so I'm not sure where the problem is here.

I'd mentioned that running `lsb_release -a` worked fine from the command line, but neglected to provide the output of that...

```
$ lsb_release -a 
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
$ echo $?
0
```

Running `hp-plugin -i -g`seems to indicate that the real problem is on hp's side...

```
hp-plugin[310176]: debug: /usr/bin/wget --cache=off --tries=3 --timeout=60 --output-document=- http://www.hp.com --spider -S
hp-plugin[310176]: debug: Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2020-05-31 09:36:45--  http://www.hp.com/
Resolving www.hp.com (www.hp.com)... 15.73.200.23, 15.73.200.22
Connecting to www.hp.com (www.hp.com)|15.73.200.23|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Server: Apache
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, max-age=7200
  Location: http://www-redirect.ext.hp.com
  Expires: Sun, 31 May 2020 15:36:45 GMT
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Date: Sun, 31 May 2020 13:36:45 GMT
  X-Varnish: 1131355252
  Age: 0
  Via: 1.1 varnish
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-Varnish-Origin: g2t3073.austin.hp.com
  X-Cache: MISS
Location: http://www-redirect.ext.hp.com [following]
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2020-05-31 09:36:45--  http://www-redirect.ext.hp.com/
Resolving www-redirect.ext.hp.com (www-redirect.ext.hp.com)... 96.7.23.193
Connecting to www-redirect.ext.hp.com (www-redirect.ext.hp.com)|96.7.23.193|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Server: AkamaiGHost
  Content-Length: 0
  Location: https://www8.hp.com/us/en/home.html
  Cache-Control: max-age=0
  Expires: Sun, 31 May 2020 13:36:45 GMT
  Date: Sun, 31 May 2020 13:36:45 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www8.hp.com/us/en/home.html [following]
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2020-05-31 09:36:45--  https://www8.hp.com/us/en/home.html
Resolving www8.hp.com (www8.hp.com)... 184.24.150.205
Connecting to www8.hp.com (www8.hp.com)|184.24.150.205|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: Apache
  Last-Modified: Sun, 31 May 2020 13:01:01 GMT
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT, DELETE
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
  Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Cache-Control: max-age=1448
  Expires: Sun, 31 May 2020 14:00:53 GMT
  Date: Sun, 31 May 2020 13:36:45 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.


hp-plugin[310176]: debug: wget returned: 0
[...] rest of error was the same.
```

But then I downloaded the file manually and got this...

```
-----------------------------------------
| PLUG-IN INSTALLATION FOR HPLIP 3.20.3 |
-----------------------------------------

  Option      Description                                       
  ----------  --------------------------------------------------
  d           Download plug-in from HP (recommended)            
  p           Specify a path to the plug-in (advanced)          
  q           Quit hp-plugin (skip installation)                

Enter option (d=download*, p=specify path, q=quit) ? p
Enter the path to the 'hplip-3.20.3-plugin.run' file (q=quit) : hplip-3.20.3-plugin.run

---------------
| COPY PLUGIN |
---------------

Downloading plug-in from: file:///home/users/jason/Downloads/hplip-3.20.3-plugin.run
Downloading plug-in: [\                                                                                                                                                                                                ] 0%     Traceback (most recent call last):
[...] rest of error the same.
```

That's the correct path, too.

**UPDATE**: I managed to get this to work, but this isn't really an "answer" or even really a "solution".  I figured I'd see if the python debugger would tell me anything new so I ran `hp-plugin` from that, with the command `pdb3 /usr/share/hplip/plugin.py  -i -g`, and, uh, it just plain worked.  It still doesn't work *without* the debugger, but at least I was able to get my printer working again.  I still cannot tell you what's wrong (and there's still something wrong here), but maybe more data will help.

Comment: Reinstall `lsb-release` with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lsb-release` and then retry.

Comment: No change.  Same result.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy hplip-gui` and `dpkg -l | grep -i hplip` to the question.

Comment: Added the output to the original question.

Comment: Just curious - will simple `lsb_release -a` crash?

Comment: Running it from the command line?  It runs fine, and returns theoretically correct data, and has an exit code of 0.  Added the specific data in the question.

Comment: Try `hp-plugin -i -g` to install plugin from terminal.

Comment: I did that, and it was the same result. `-i -g` doesn't appear to do anything special aside from non-gui mode.  Ahh!  But there were messages that scrolled past before this which I have just added to the question.

Comment: This seems to be https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1899264

Answer (score 6):

The debug option worked for me, but as a second step I had to type "cont" and press <kbd>Return</kbd> to get the depicted process to run.

Comment: thank you! This worked!!
`pdb3 /usr/share/hplip/plugin.py  -i -g`
followed by
`cont`

Comment: Had to do this as well. In addition, I did not have a pdb3 command available but found that's merely an alias for `python3 -m pdb` so `python3 -m pdb /usr/share/hplip/plugin.py  -i -g` did the job for me. Should say this was on Fedora 32, but suppose it might affect others too.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I can confirm that with the debug option the scanner plugin gets installed.

```
pdb3 /usr/share/hplip/plugin.py  -i -g
```

Comment: Yeah me too, odd...

Answer (score 1):

I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04. I have a HP LaserJet Pro MFP M226dw. It is a multi-function printer supporting both printing and scanning. I similarly had difficulty with scanning. Fortunately, I was able to get printing work earlier.

I already had `hplip-3.21.2.run` installed in my system. I believed that the problem was with the scanner plugin. The automatic command to download the plugin shown above did not work. So, I manually downloaded the [latest script](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/plugins) from the HPLip website.

Then, I ran this command to install the plugin:

```
sh hplip-3.21.2-plugin.run
```

That fixed the scanner for me. Now, I am able to scan without any issues.