# HPLIP cannot detect printer HP Laserjet 100 Colot MPF M175nw

Tags: networking, printing, hp, scanner, hplip

New installation of **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS**

Printer HP Laserjet 100 Colot MPF M175nw30 cannot be detected by **hlip-3.21.4**

Everithing seems to work properly but "Printer is not HPLIP installed" so that I cannot use scanner. I tried all troubleshooting but I MUST be missing something. Can anyone help?

Below you can find all the information (**Firewall is inactive**)

http://www.agriviva.it/HLIP_and_Ubuntu_20.pdf

Comment: Google, linux HP Laserjet 100 Color MFP M175nw → one of the first hits is this https://beeznest.com/blog/2015/03/16/configure-hp-laserjet-100-colormfp-m175nw-scanner-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you. I guess the problem was with the manual install of hlip-3.21.4 package from HP support page.

After running

sudo apt-get install hplip 

and

sudo hp-setup

The first time nothing happened. The same error "no printer detected". 
The second time the printer was finally detected!

At this point there was ANOTHER ISSUE: The automatic command (hp-plugin) to download the plugin did not work.

Comment: I have solved following the discussion in

[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245010/hplip-driver-install-fails-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Although I already had hplip-3.21.4.run installed in my system. I manually downloaded the latest script from the HPLip website [link](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/plugins) and run 

sh hplip-3.21.4-plugin.run

Finally the printer was succesfully installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Knud Larsen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341034/hplip-cannot-detect-printer-hp-laserjet-100-colot-mpf-m175nw/1341811#comment2290993_1341034) for sharing [the resource](https://beeznest.com/blog/2015/03/16/configure-hp-laserjet-100-colormfp-m175nw-scanner-on-ubuntu/).

I guess the problem was with the manual install of `hlip-3.21.4` package from the HP support page.

After running:

```
sudo apt-get install hplip
```

and:

```
sudo hp-setup
```

the first time nothing happened. I had the same error:

```
no printer detected
```

The second time I have issued the command `sudo hp-setup`, the printer was finally detected!

At this point there was another issue: the automatic command (`hp-plugin`) to download the plugin did not work.

I have solved the problem following the discussion in this question in Ask Ubuntu: [HPLIP Driver install fails on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245010/hplip-driver-install-fails-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Although I already had `hplip-3.21.4.run` installed in my system, I manually downloaded the latest script from the [HPLIP website](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/plugins) and ran:

```
sh hplip-3.21.4-plugin.run
```

Finally the printer was successfully installed.